# Unrecognised selector when calling binding method

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to bind a basic Objective-C library I have created to a Xamarin project. The .h file is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import UIKit;

@interface StarIOFunctions : NSObject {

}

+ (NSMutableData *)GetDataToSendToPrinter:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

I have tried to create my binding with the following ApiDefinition:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
namespace BindingTake2
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface StarIOFunctions {
        [Export ("GetDataToSendToPrinter:image")]
        NSMutableData GetDataToSendToPrinter (UIImage image);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles, but when I run it in my application:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("image1.png");
StarIOFunctions functions = new StarIOFunctions ();
var output = functions.GetDataToSendToPrinter (image);
```

My application crashes with the following error:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[StarIOFunctions GetDataToSendToPrinter:image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7cdb50f0
```

Now, I think it has something to do with me sending an image, and not a pointer to the image - but I'm totally lost and can't work out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're including the parameter names in the selector name, i.e.

```
[Export ("GetDataToSendToPrinter:image")]
```

should be:

```
[Export ("GetDataToSendToPrinter:")]
```

The last column ':' indicates that a parameter is needed - but you do not need to name it (in the selector) as the previous string should imply it.